# Perform action after a popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, php, timer, popup, popupwindow

On the main page I have a timer that I can set initially. When the time goes off, a popup window apprears with a quiz that must be completed. I have a variable $correctQuestions that stores the number of correct answers from that quiz.

What I want is a PHP function for a button to close the popup window and add restart the timer, adding 30 seconds to the initial time if all questions were answered correctly, and remove 30 elsewise. How could that be done?

Edit: 
On the timer PHP file I have buttons to call functions to increase/decrease time from the timer script in js, and a button to start the timer:

```
<button id="Start-Stop" onclick="clickButton();">START</button>
```

When the time is off, the popup window appears with a set of questions from a database

Here's the script with the function that the button calls:

```
function clickButton()
{
  // Code which is not so relevant for my question
  document.getElementById("errorLabel").innerHTML = "";
  displayTime();
  document.getElementById("Start-Stop").innerHTML = "Stop";
  start = true;
  chosenTime = time;  
  timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  // Show the time left
  document.getElementById("initialTimeLabel").innerHTML = "Time until exercise:";
} // clickButton

function tick()
{
  if(time == 0)
  {
    clearInterval(timer);
    openWindow();
  }
  else
  {
    time = time - 1;
  }
  displayTime();
}

function openWindow()
{
  // Choose the selected module and popup an excercise page
  var module = document.getElementById("moduleDropdown");
  module = module.options[module.selectedIndex].text;
  var mylink = "ExercisePage.php?module=" + module;
  var windowname = "Questions";
  start = false;
  time = chosenTime;
  displayTime();
  document.getElementById("moduleDropdown").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("initialTimeLabel").innerHTML = "Set an initial time:";
  document.getElementById("Start-Stop").innerHTML = "Start";
  var myWindow = window.open(mylink, windowname, "type=fullwindow,fullscreen=yes,height=screen.availHeight,width=screen.availWidth,left=0,top=0,resizeable=no,scrollbars=yes");
  myWindow.focus();
}
```

And when I press the button to close the popup window I want my timer to restart with +30 seconds if all questions are answered correctly (I have a variable $correctQuestions to count them) and +30 seconds otherwise.

Comment: you might be using ajax or jquery for that pupose. are you using any thng like that. whould you like to show us your code.

Comment: @K.Uzair Thanks for the response! I edited the question and added some of my code to it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have launched the popup like

```
var myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com", "Google", "width=800, height=600");
```

But then if you want to check whether popup has closed or not

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
  if (myWindow.closed) {
    // Do some stuf here as this will run when the popup has been closed
    alert("Child window closed");
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 500);
```

And if you want to close the popup on some button click, or after an interval

```
$myBtn.click(function () {
  myWindow.close();
  // other code here to reset your timers etc
});
```